# How can I change the height of mathematical equations in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

How can I change the height of mathematical equations in Microsoft Word 2013?

Example: I would like to change the height of the following selected equation:

[image]

to have the same the height as the following selected equation:

[image]

I use Microsoft Word 2013 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I cannot use LaTeX (constrained by my editor).

Here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4y6Mj_UZoTEVnVEcEtVaWRiYjA) from which I took the example ([Google preview isn't able to show mathematical equations](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/9nXrV8jVmHY;context-place=forum/drive) so it needs to be downloaded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the end of the equation that has too large of a gap under it.
2. Hit the "Delete" key to bring the equation below up and directly onto the end of it:

[image: Problematic Equations]

3. Then to put it back on it's own line use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Using Shift+Enter will force a "Line break", instead of the "Paragraph break" Word likes to use when you hit Enter, thus reducing the gap:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, I had incorrectly assumed that the vertical space was within the mathematical equation.